# Passing array of integers to loop, modify the array, and store results in new array. Project Euler #8 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops

I'm working through problem 8 on project Euler and have looked through a bunch of resources.  Here is the problem:

"#8 - Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number."

I split the 1000-digt number into an array of strings and converted that to an array of integers.

```
number = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

digits = number.split('').reject!{|i| (i=="\n")}   

integer_digits = digits.map {|i| i.to_i}
```

From here, I want to take the first five values, multiple them, and take the resulting value and add it to a new array named "products".  I'm trying to remove the first value of the integer_digit array with the .shift method, start the loop over with the second value of the array, and storing the next product of values [1..5] in the integer_digits array...and so on...

```
getproduct=1

products=[]


loop do 
    products << integer_digits[0..4].map {|x| (getproduct*=x) }.max
    integer_digits.shift
    break if integer_digits.length < 5
  end

puts products.max
```

Once the loop went through all the digits, I hoped that I could display the greatest value using the .max method.   The code I have returns an empty array...

My question:  How do I keep adding the resulting value of the loop to the product array until there are less than five integer_digit values left?  And will the .max method work once this is done?

Comment: I'm downvoting this question as you are asking how to solve a challenge in the community. I don't thinks it's a good practice to find other to solve your challenges.

Comment: Hint: this is a great use case for [Enumerable#each_cons](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
products << integer_digits[0..4].map {|x| (getproduct*=x) }.max
```

makes very little sense. What you need is:

```
products << integer_digits.first(5).inject(:*)
```

However you shouldn't store all the results, you only need the biggest one:

```
max = 0
while integer_digits.length >= 5
  product = integer_digits.first(5).inject(:*)
  max = product if product > max
  integer_digits.shift
end

puts max #=> 40824
```

UPDATE:

The reason why you are getting an empty string is most likely caused by running the loop twice without regenerating `integer_digits` array (which has 4 elements after the loop)

Also as suggested by @MarkThomas, you can use `each_cons` method:

```
integer_digits.each_cons(5).inject(0) {|max, ary| [max, ary.inject(:*)].max }
```

This has this advantage that it will not modify integer_digits, so you can run it mutliple times over the same set of digits.

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos - Could you explain why? AFAIK they are just for self-improvement and hence suits very well into SO.

Comment: Well, If that would be the question `Here is the question. How to do this`, then I agree. However he did show his attempt to solve the problem which just happened not to work, hence it is clear that he tried to solve it by himself and now is trying to understand why it is not working.

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos I understand what you're saying, and I've been doing the "just try it and google it until you solve it" approach.  But I also know that at a certain point, you're wasting time without progress.  I'm simply here to try to think about this in a different way and to understand why my code doesn't work.

Comment: I'ts ok, I was just sharing my concerns about this kind of questions. Removing downvote and deleting comments.

Comment: @BroiSatse that's a lot cleaner, thanks!  I knew the getproduct variable felt very sloppy but it was the easiest way I could wrap my head around.  Why, though, would the original code not store any values in products array?

Comment: @user3738855 - The only reason which springs to mind is that you tried to run this loop twice. Since you are shifting elements from the array, the second run will not even iterate once.